# Can I install curseradio using APT?

Tags: software-installation

I recently upgraded to Lubuntu 20.04 and all the efforts to get it installed and working from sites I've found are not working. Is there anyway to install that using APT?

Answer (score 1):

Maintainer of curseradio don't offer the deb packages themselves. Intead they [offer](https://github.com/chronitis/curseradio) Python scripts. However, you can install using [Alin Andrei's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8). APT will use this PPA to fetch curseradio and its dependencies. To install, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt install curseradio
```

Comment: I followed this and then tried to run curseradio , this is the report

Comment: @James What is the report?

Comment: I tried this but I get let a list of messages james@shire$ curseradio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/curseradio", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._b